# WiFi Not working in After Installation in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, network-manager

all

I am facing a problem with my wireless.
When I tried Ubuntu 16.04 Live, Wireless was working fine, but after installation Wireless is not working,

My Machine in HCL ME (i3). The Machine has special key to enable and disable wireless, and the hot key works, when I am toggling the key Wireless networking is enabling and disabling according in the Network manager applet but available WiFi networks are not shown.

Any Solution ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: Please run the ubuntu forums wireless script (github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and paste the results into paste.ubuntu.com then edit your question to include a link to it

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and restart network manager
sudo service network-manager restart

There is something wrong with dnsmasq in Mint 18 and 18.1
Just edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and change dns=dnsmasq to #dns=dnsmasq.